# Get the information of whether this MS SQL job completed or not on the particular date in the past

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can get the job name from `[sysjobs]`, the result of execution from `[sysjobhistory].[run_status]`. But where can i get the exact time and date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These integers *are* the actual date and time digits, eg a job that runs on `2015-09-09 06:23:45` will have a run_date of `20150909` and a `run_time` of `62335`

Luckily, you don't need to play with the digits to retrieve an actual `datetime` value. You can use the `agent_datetime` function eg:

```
SELECT TOP 5
    [JobName]     = JOB.name,
    [StepName]    = HIST.step_name,
    [RunDateTime] = dbo.agent_datetime(HIST.run_date,HIST.run_time)
FROM
    sysjobs JOB
INNER JOIN    
    sysjobhistory HIST ON HIST.job_id = JOB.job_id
ORDER BY 
    run_date DESC, run_time DESC
```

Found [here](http://sqlandme.com/2013/07/22/sql-server-get-values-as-datetime-from-sysjobhistory/) and [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/13/sql-server-interesting-function-agent_datetime/)

For filtering purposes though you can simply compare against the digit representation of the filter date or number, eg:

```
where run_date >20151001
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this on msdb database:

```
SELECT [instance_id]
  ,[job_id]
  ,[step_id]
  ,[step_name]
  ,[sql_message_id]
  ,[sql_severity]
  ,[message]
  ,[run_status]
  ,[run_date]
  ,[run_time]
  ,[run_duration]
  ,[operator_id_emailed]
  ,[operator_id_netsent]
  ,[operator_id_paged]
  ,[retries_attempted]
  ,[server]
  FROM [dbo].[sysjobhistory]
```

GO

Comment: `[run_time]` in this table is not exactly what i need. The format of it is `int`, i need something like this `2015-10-16 04:00:00.000`

Comment: @AvsenevSlava Use the function MSDB.DBO.AGENT_DATETIME to convert the int value to datetime.
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/13/sql-server-interesting-function-agent_datetime/  http://sqlandme.com/2013/07/22/sql-server-get-values-as-datetime-from-sysjobhistory/